# HTTP Requests when article is added to Jekyll blog

Tags: httprequest, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I need to send a HTTP request every time I add an article to my Jekyll blog. What is the best means to achieve this?

Specifically, I wish to be able to add posts on my social media (Twitter,Facebook,Instagram,LinkedIn) every time I add a blog to my website. I felt that IFTTT best suites my needs, but if there are other **free** alternatives, then Im open for a change.

Comment: This question (how you asked it) is not very suitable for Stack Overflow as you have framed it as a software selection question. I have added the appropriate close vote. If you delete the second part, however, and change 'what is the best means to achieve' to 'how to achieve' this, this it is a good SO question, because it is not longer software selection or opinion related. The key is to never ask for the 'best' or for 'other tools'. Sounds petty, but those are the rules. Good luck with Jekyll!

Answer (score -2):

### How to add an HTTP request after an article is added to a Jekyll blog?

There are three options.

1. Let a service watch your RSS feed, like IFTTT or Zapier.
2. Write a plugin that does this for you on build time.
3. Call the URL manually after you post your blog.